# How do I get VS 2019 to break on System.InvalidCastException?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I'm working on a UWP app. While debugging it in VS 2019 I get this in the Output window:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException'

But VS 2019 doesn't break there. I've tried finding a way to making VS 2019 break on this error, but haven't been able to. I'm sure it can be done, but I've not been able to find how to make VS 2019 break on that error. How do I modify VS 2019 break on that error?

Comment: Did you try setting the checkbox for 'Break when thrown' for the InvalidCastException?

Comment: [just like in all VS versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019#tell-the-debugger-to-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown)

Comment: No Pawell, because I don't know where it is. 

Thank you, @magicandre!

Comment: When you set the checkbox for InvalidCastException, can it break on that error successfully?

Comment: ok, I've posted it as answer.

Comment: Yes, Faywang, it does break on that error successfully. Glad it did, as I learned what the problem was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open your solution and in the `Exception Settings` window (VS menu item `Debug` -> `Windows` -> `Exception Settings`), type `System.InvalidCastException` into search:

[image]

and select the [checkbox to configure Visual Studio debugger to stop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019#tell-the-debugger-to-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown).